# How can I tell if my wired ethernet connection is using 802.1X authentication on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter, wired, ieee802.1x

From a command prompt (or a script) I'd like to be able to query the wired interface to determine if it has succesfully established an 802.1X connection, or if it has fallen back to unauthenticated access or not.

I am doing 802.1X testing in a lab environment and need a way to automate validation of successful 802.1X connectivity.

**UPDATE**: To be clear, I'm referring to 802.1X (dot 1 x), not wireless 802.11. Also, 802.1X is often used over wired ethernet connections (as well as wireless).

Also, for more detail on using 802.1X in wired environments, SANS has a great whitepaper discussing it: http://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/authentication/implementing-ieee-8021x-wired-networks-34520

[image]

Comment: @Mick - Your lack of clarity is the reason two people made the same mistake.  802.1X is an authentication standard.  You didn't make it clear you were talking about authentication instead of 802.11 ( wireless ) and/or 802.3 ( ethernet ).

Comment: @Ramhound, my question is explicitly clear on terminology. You didn't read my question very carefully, because I am *not* referring to wireless technology at all. I used the terms "wired" and 802.1X and even tagged it as such.

Comment: @Mick - Two people made the same mistake thinking you were talking about 802.11 instead of 802.1X.  The tag you used has no description which means it is pretty much useless.  I read your question and I was confused and was not alone in this thought.

Comment: @Ramhound I suspect 2 people made the mistake because 802.1X can be easily misread as 802.11. It's a common oversight and no big deal.